# MAX function returns 0 when using a column made from REGEXEXTRACT

Tags: google-sheets

Consider the following :

```
A           B       C
Item1-240  240    FALSE
Item2-280  280    TRUE
Item3-230  230    FALSE
```

B is the result of `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"\d+")`
I want the C column to return =B1=MAX(B1:B3)

C is working fine with "raw" input numbers on B. But when I extract them, inspecting MAX(B1:B3) returns 0.

The ideal goal in the end is to make conditonal color formating on A if C is true.

This is very confusing to me, and I'm thankful for any tips on why this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Try with:*

```js
=value(REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"\d+"))
```

OR

```js
=--REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"\d+")
```

Comment: The value did the trick, many thanks!